# Joomla 2.5: mod_login is redirecting to com_user when the username/password is wrong

Tags: joomla, authentication, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I am using mod_login for my Joomla Website. It works properly. But whenever there is a wrong username/password it's redirecting to com_user instead of mod_login. When I put wrong info it goes to the following page:

```
http://my_joomla_site/component/users/?view=login
```

How can i remove this com_user taking over of my mod_login? In case of wrong username/pass i want it to redirect to the mod_login page with an error message.

Comment: A module is not a component... The com_user takes over because Joomla can't send you to a module when the user details are wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my comment, a module is not a component... The com_user takes over because Joomla can't send you to a module when the user details are wrong.

I believe you have a module in a certain menu item and you want the user to be redirected to that menu in case of wrong username/password.

I had the same problem, and found this plugin:
[Core Login Redirect](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/login-redirect/12395)

It allows you to customize the destination of various cases, and doesn't require editing core files, as it would be my second suggestion (it works, but with the plugin there is no need to go this route):

http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=1296923#p1296923

Comment: Thank you for the detail explanation. I will follow your suggestion..thanks